# SQL subquery using group by item from main query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table with a `created` timestamp and `id` identifier.

I can get number of unique `id`'s per week with:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created)::date AS week, count(distinct id) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;
```

Now I want to have the accumulated number of `created` by unique `id`'s per week, something like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created)::date AS week, count(distinct id),
       (SELECT count(distinct id)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE date_trunc('week', created)::date <= week) as acc
FROM my_table
GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;
```

But that doesn't work, as `week` is not accessible in the sub select (`ERROR: column "week" does not exist`).

How do I solve this?

I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cumulative aggregation.  But, I don't think you need the `distinct`, so:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created)::date AS week, count(*) as cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(created)) as running_cnt
FROM my_table
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

In any case, as you've phrased the problem, you can change `cnt` to use `count(distinct)`.  Your subquery is not using `distinct` at all.

Comment: Thanks! The missing `distinct` was an error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

CTEs or a temp table should fix your problem. Here is an example using CTEs.

```
 WITH abc AS (
     SELECT date_trunc('week', created)::date AS week, count(distinct id) as IDCount
     FROM my_table
     GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;
 )

SELECT abc.week, abc.IDcount,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE date_trunc('week', created)::date <= adc.week) as acc
FROM abc
GROUP BY week ORDER BY abc.week;
```

Hope this helps